# Listing all the clients connected to a room in Socket.io version > 1

Tags: node.js, socket.io, migration

After the io.sockets.clients() method has been depreciated from the later versions of Socket.io, and after my research couldn't find any documentation on the socket.io offical web.

Morever, it gives the type error for clients() method as below:

> **TypeError:** undefined is not a function

Has anyone figured out how to list all the connected clients in a room with the later versions of Socket.io?

Comment: The best thing to do is keep track of them as they connect.  Socket.IO should be your transport layer, not your session manager.

Comment: Okay. In my project I have 2 socket variables set for client client. Is there anyway to loop through these variables for all clients and see if the match?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To get socket IDs of the clients connected to a room use this code:

```
var namespace = '/';
var roomName = 'my_room_name';
for (var socketId in io.nsps[namespace].adapter.rooms[roomName]) {
    console.log(socketId);
}
```

**Edit:**

To get socket by socket ID you may try this:

```
var socket = io.sockets.connected[socketId];
```

Comment: You have once again helped me significantly! I appreciate it.

Comment: That's really useful. Could you tell me where you found this? I didn't see any clue on socket.io's official site. @CuriousGuy

Comment: @TonyChen I didn't find this in the official docs too. I just explored socket.io objects myself with `console.log`

Comment: @TonyChen exploring socket.io source code helps as well :)

Comment: Thank you, saved me a lot time after reading of old solutions not related to v1 of socket.io

Answer (score -2):

In Socket.IO 1.4

To get the array of All connected Users :

```
// io.sockets.connected returns an Object with socketId as its key 

var allConnectedClients = Object.keys(io.sockets.connected);// This will return the array of SockeId of all the connected clients
```

To get the Count of all clients :

```
var clientsCount = io.engine.clientsCount ; // This will return the count of connected clients
```

Comment: This answer does not describe how to get all clients *in a room*.