# Emit to a room, and use each socket's individual property as a parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'd like to emit a function to a room of sockets, giving the function a parameter that is specific to each socket.

In my code, this specific variable is the player's number. When a socket joins the room, this property is set depending on how many players are already in the game. For example:

```
socket.player = 1;
```

All of the sockets in my room will have a value for `socket.player`. In short, the function emitted to each socket in the room should have that socket's `.player` property as the parameter. To clarify, I'm emitting from outside of any `socket.on` scope.

Comment: why emit a whole function?

Comment: also your clarification makes things worse not better.... could some code be rendered please

Comment: @Daemedeor I'm emitting a string which is the name of a function on client side. `io.to('roomName').emit('function name', socket.player);` is what I want to do, but that wouldn't get the `socket.player` of each socket in the room.

Comment: you'll need to keep track of it in some common place because the socket is a standalone object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153053/listing-all-the-clients-connected-to-a-room-in-socket-io-version-1 check this SO out, it might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var namespace = '/';
var roomName = 'my_room_name';
for (var socketId in io.nsps[namespace].adapter.rooms[roomName]) {
    var socket = io.sockets.connected[socketId];
    socket.emit('function name', socket.player);
}
```

Dont be afraid to use emit inside a for loop when needed, actually socket.io is using the same thing when you broadcast or emiting in a room.

Comment: Yeah, this is basically what I arrived at, except I have `io.sockets.adapter.rooms[roomName]`. `sockets` is the default namespace for anyone wondering